# Conceptual difference between TensorFlow (graph-mode) and JAX

Tags: tensorflow, jax

## TensorFlow

TensorFlow (in graph-mode) generates a computation graph and `tf.gradients` is implemented as an operation on the graph, which outputs a new graph for the gradient.

For execution, there are different options: It could directly operate on the graph, or it could compile it to XLA, or you could also transform it to TFLite, etc.

## JAX

JAX operates on functions. `jax.grad` gets a function and returns a function.

For execution, there are different options, but I think the most common is to compile to XLA.

## Question

So, this both sounds very similar to me. A computation graph is just another way to represent a function. Is there any conceptual difference?

I often see that people say that `jax.vmap` is one big advantage of JAX, but you can do just the same in TensorFlow, e.g. [`tf.vectorized_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/vectorized_map).

Or phrased a bit different: Is there any algorithm which you could implement in JAX but not in TF in the same way, or vice versa? Or which would be efficient in one case but not in the other?

This question is really only about the conceptual aspect, which should be a purely objective thing to answer: Either the answer is yes, they are conceptually the same (equally powerful), maybe with a short explanation, or no, they are conceptually different, with an example what is possible in one framework but conceptually not possible on the other. I don't want to have any discussion here on any subjective aspect, e.g. that maybe `tf.vectorized_map` is a bit buggy, that TF documentation is worse, or whatever.

Comment: It's not clear to me what answer you're looking for? You're correct that JAX and tensorflow graph mode have conceptual overlaps, but they're different packages with different designs. Can you be more concrete about what information you're seeking?

Comment: The (imo rather wonderful) lecture notes at https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc2541_2021/ give a great deal of informed info on JAX - in particular the link titled 'NNTD Chapter 2' goes through several operations in JAX that are not (afaik) easily available in Tensorflow, and the two JAX tutorials linked in the left column might also be worth looking at.

Comment: @DavidHarris Thanks for the link. But all of these things, like forward-mode autodiff are also possible in TensorFlow. It probably can use a similar implementation as in JAX, transforming the computation graph.

Comment: @jakevdp I wonder if there is a real conceptual/technical difference, in what is theoretically possible with either approach. E.g. PyTorch is strictly different, on a conceptual level. Or maybe on a conceptual level, there is no difference between TF and JAX, and the differences are just the API and other design decisions? This is what I want to understand.

Comment: @Albert My memory on those notes is a bit rusty, but I think remember him saying that dealing with Jacobians (and similarly Jacobian-vector products and vector-Jacobian products) is poorly (or not at all?) supported in TF, but easy to do and efficient in JAX. Similarly Hessians. That doesn't amount to a conceptual difference, however, even if it might make JAX a better tool than TF for some researchers.

Comment: @DavidHarris But that is not true. Those are supported, and I think the implementation is actually conceptually pretty similar to how JAX does it.

Comment: This seems far too open-ended/opinion driven to be a good StackOverflow question.

Comment: @jakevdp: Why? I'm only asking about a very technical thing here. Either it is the same conceptually (implying that you can conceptually have exactly the same implementation e.g. for backprop, forward-mode autodiff, everything else), or not. There is nothing really in between. This can clearly be answered. To me it looks like the answer is a very clear "yes", but maybe I'm understanding sth wrong, or missing some aspect, so that's why I'm asking. If the answer is "no", it can give a clear example what is impossible in one but possible in the other, or would need a very different impl.

Comment: Well, agree to disagree I guess. I answer a lot of the JAX SO questions, and this is one that (to me) does not seem answerable in this forum. You might have better luck finding an answer in another forum that lends itself better to more ambiguous and open-ended questions, such as https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/new

Comment: @jakevdp Thanks for the suggestion. I posted it [here](https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/12202). I also extended my question here, to make it maybe a bit more clear. I think there is really only either a yes or a no answer.

Comment: It depends on what efficient means for you. For instance one can quickly get the derivative of a loss w.r.t input data on Jax but it requires clearly more code on Tensorflow. From how many additional lines is it considered less efficient? etc...

Comment: @ValentinGoldité I don't mean the current API and measured in amount of code, but I mean algorithmically, runtime complexity, conceptually.

Comment: Conceptually you can do everything with one of these framework. Just sometimes it will require a lot of time and energy. That's why as far I'm concerned you should take into account the coding time. For instance to compute a Hessian it is quite optimized on Jax thanks to forwardprop. You can also do it in Tensorflow but (until recently) it was not implemented officially...

Comment: @ValentinGoldité But that's not true. E.g. PyTorch does not allow for the same things due to its eager execution mode. And my question here is not about development time or energy, I am just interested about it on a conceptual level here in this question, nothing else (so that this question is a purely objective technical question, nothing subjective).